# what is the isar databse file extension?

Tags: flutter-isar

I use sqflite in flutter because i am able to find the databse file and save it for many use later.
But when i started to use isar db i could not find the db file at all.

I tried **path** and **path provider** to find the directory like this

```
final directory = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
final Isar isar = await Isar.open([IsarEmailSchema], directory: directory.path);
```

with no success.

So what is the isar database extension and how to find the db files acrros platforms?

Answer (score -3):

The file extension for an ISAR (Integrated Station Automated Reporting) database is usually ".mdb", which stands for Microsoft Access Database.

The database file extension for Isar database is not specified. It is a self-contained database that operates on the file system and doesn't require a separate database server to function.

As per the information available, Isar uses SQLite database under the hood, but the actual file extension could be different as it might be using a custom wrapper on top of SQLite.

In order to find the Isar database file, you could try to use the getDatabasesPath method from the Flutter path_provider package to get the path to the database file, then append the name of the database file to it.
For example:

```
java
final directory = await getDatabasesPath();
final String dbPath = directory.path + "/isar_database.db";
final Isar isar = await Isar.open([IsarEmailSchema], dbPath);
```

This should give you the path to the Isar database file, which you can then use to locate the file across platforms.